# Link anchors in same don't work in all browsers

Tags: html, anchor, hyperlink

I had to create some pages for legal docs for a client and I came across this problem. I had to use a lot of id attributes to link to specific sections from inside the page, but none of them is working.

I followed the method as described in w3schools.

So I have the id element 
`<h4 id="a1">Some text</h4>` and then I point to it like this `<a class="specialLink" href="#a1">Click here</a>`

Went through several threads on google and here but didn't help.

Any ideas?

Also here's a [link](http://topgreekgyms.gr/terms/) to the website. You can see the anchors in the third tab and you can use the password 'enter' to get in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried using an anchor instead of h4?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with anchors and hyperlinks, those are working fine (though you really should distrust w3schools... http://w3fools.com/ ).

If you copy the content of your tab into a single page all the hyperlinks are working with the markup that is already there.

The real issue is the scrolling control.

You have a container with some custom scrolling controllers (the hint was class="mCSB_scrollTools") that's preventing the page to scroll to the sections which you want to show. Another test that you can do is try to find on the page "Deals;" and (at least in Chrome) you will notice a flicker when the browser tries to display that section and then scrolls (better yet teleports) to the top of the page.

I have close to zero Wordpress experience so, sadly, this is how far I can help you. Maybe you can change some configuration on the scroll box or just use a normal container...

Comment: That was the conclusion I was getting to as well.
Do you think I can fix this using some javascript?
Thank you for your advise on w3schools! Is there another documentation I should use as a reference point?

Comment: I suppose that you can do it through JS, though it might be tricky to get everything to work together smoothly. I would first try to see if the components that you have already on the page support what you need. Having said that, there is also this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/
Regarding documentation, here are some resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ http://www.webplatform.org/

Comment: I'll check them both and let you know the results. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a name="a1">some text</a>`

Comment: Did you do it on the place you want to link to? Not the actual link that you click.

Comment: Yes, that's right I replaced the 'id' with 'name'.
I'm starting to thinking that perhaps has something to do with the fact that the container has a different scroll bar than the page's.
Did you get a change to take a look on the website?